# php directory index is 403 forbidden with nginx and php-fpm

Tags: php, apache, nginx

I followed the instructions on the arch linux wiki to get a site running using nginx + php and without using apache webserver.
For some reason, I'm getting the 403 forbidden error when I try to access the directories that I set up in the nginx config. Here's the config:

```
server {
  server_name myserver.me;
    location /webmail {
        alias /usr/share/webapps/roundcubemail;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/roundcube_access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/roundcube_error.log;
    }
    # Robots file
    location ~ ^/webmail/robots.txt {
        allow all;
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
    }
    # Deny Protected directories 
    location ~ ^/webmail/(config|temp|logs)/ {
         deny all;
    }
    location ~ ^/webmail/(README|INSTALL|LICENSE|CHANGELOG|UPGRADING)$ {
        deny all;
    }
    location ~ ^/webmail/(bin|SQL)/ {
        deny all;
    }
    # Hide .md files
    location ~ ^/webmail/(.+\.md)$ {
        deny all;
    }
    # Hide all dot files
    location ~ ^/webmail/\. {
        deny all;
        access_log off;
        log_not_found off;
    }
    #Roundcube fastcgi config
    location ~ /webmail(/.*\.php)$ {
        include fastcgi.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^/webmail/(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /usr/share/webapps/roundcubemail/$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
        fastcgi_param PHP_VALUE open_basedir="/tmp/:/var/cache/roundcubemail:/usr/share/webapps/roundcubemail:/etc/webapps/roundcubemail:/usr/share/pear/:/var/log/roundcubemail";
    }
}
```

}

Why am I getting this error? It's saying that the directory index is forbidden. I know this is a common problem, but I have little php experience, especially with nginx.

Comment: Just to be sure, have you restarted the nginx  server? This issue sometimes arises when changes are made and the server isn't restarted.

Comment: yes ive restarted it many times